# Google CloudBuild does not fetch latest commits and branches with a large monorepo

Tags: github, google-cloud-platform, continuous-integration, continuous-deployment, google-cloud-build

I'm using Google CloudBuild for continuous deployment cycle of my large monorepo which is on Github.

The CD cycle seems to work as expected with **master** branch but not with other branches.

- If I add a new branch in my github repo, it does not get shown in cloudbuild UI.
- If I push code to an existing branch, my trigger for the same branch in cloudbuild does not get triggered.

**I think this might be a cloudbuild bug, since I think I'm doing everything according to the docs.**

Comment: Did you figure this out?